# Retrieve multiple files from same directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-files

I am creating a GUI program that has 25 buttons, each accesses a unique file in the same folder, I know I can individually program each one to go to each file, but that seems like a lot more code than there needs to be, is there a more efficient way to do this?
here is the code:

```
box1 = 'C:/Users/Geekman2/Documents/Tests/box1.txt
cupcake = Button(donut,text = "Box #1", command = open(box1))
```

done this way I would have to create a variable for every file,not very efficient

P.S. if you are confused, I name all of my variables after pastries

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the code you wanted help optimizing.

Comment: Write a python program to write a python program that will hardcode all the filepaths.

Comment: "P.S. if you are confused, I name all of my variables after pastries" - I would get over that habit *real* fast if I were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try a code snippet similar to this:

```
directory = 'C:/Users/Geekman2/Documents/Tests/'
...
def AddDirTo(filename)
     return directory + filename
```

Then the code you posted would turn into:

```
box1 = AddDirTo('box1.txt') #note: you did close box1's quote on your question
cupcake = Button(donut,text = "Box #1", command = open(box1))
```

If every file you have is a text file, as is indicated from the question's tays, you can even make it:

```
directory = 'C:/Users/Geekman2/Documents/Tests/'
extension = '.txt'
...
def AddDirTo(filename):
     return directory + filename + extension
...
box1 = AddDirTo('box1') #note: you did close box1's quote on your question
cupcake = Button(donut,text = "Box #1", command = open(box1))
```

For those of you about to vote this down for the `directory` and `extension`variables at the top, it makes the code reusable for other directories and extensions, without having to make a new function.